# SDK47 update results in app.config Constants not being found by Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I am [following instructions](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-47-a0f6f5c038af) for updating Expo from 46 to 47.  Overall it's going well, however, a Jest test is failing when trying to read my `app.config`'s `API_URL` environment variable:

my jest config is using:
 `preset: 'jest-expo',`

```
const API_URL = Constants?.manifest?.extra?.api;
```

I read:

> With SDK 46, one notable change was to move from Constants.manifest.extra to Constants.expoConfig.extra.

```
const API_URL = Constants?.expoConfig?.extra?.api;
```

However, the result is still `undefined`

What could have changed from SDK 46 to 47 causing this failure?

I have also tried mocking the `expo-constants` library:

```
jest.mock('expo-constants', () => {
  return {
    extra: {
      api: 'myfull URL',
    },
  };
});
```

And this also does not seem to have an impact on the output.  Thanks for clarifications

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have skipped the `expoConfig` property in the returned value.

```js
jest.mock('expo-constants', () => {
  return {
    expoConfig: {
      extra: {
        api: 'myfull URL',
      },
    }
  };
});
```